# How to apply PostGIS ST_Within to all rows in a column

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-11

I'm trying to use PostGIS to determine what political district (polygon) each geo-location took place in. In one table I have the shapefile loaded into a table called 113th_congress_shp, and in the other I have a list of events that took place given in the form POINT(long lat) in a table called gdelt_full_geo. My goal is to be able to apply ST_Within to each event in a particular column and have it return the political district that it applies to.

I'm coming from more of an R background so I am used to being able to do vector operations on an entire column. So, I am wondering how to do that in PostgreSQL. Using the following code I am able to get one row:

```sql
SELECT statefp, cd113fp, geoid, namelsad
FROM public."113th_congress_shp"
WHERE ST_Within(ST_SetSRID((SELECT action_coord FROM public.gdelt_full_geo LIMIT 1), 4269)::geometry, geom);
```

However, when I do:

```sql
SELECT statefp, cd113fp, geoid, namelsad
FROM public."113th_congress_shp"
WHERE ST_Within(ST_SetSRID((SELECT action_coord FROM public.gdelt_full_geo), 4269)::geometry, geom);
```

I get the following error:

> "ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an
>   expression SQL state: 21000"

When I do the following, I get every globaleventid from the gdelt_full_geo table where the lat long falls within a polygon from the 113th_congress_shp table. However, I am unable to join the specific statefp and namelsad that the point falls into from the 113th_congress_shp table to the globaleventid from the gdelt_full_geo table so that I know what polygon the eventid belongs to.

```sql
SELECT a.globaleventid
FROM public.gdelt_test a
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT x.statefp, x.namelsad
        FROM public."113th_congress_shp" x
        WHERE ST_Within((
                ST_SetSRID(a.action_coord , 4269))::geometry
                , x.geom)
        ) 
        ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the suggestion from @wildplasser I was able to start digging in the right direction and was able to achieve what I wanted, such that all geoeventid's were joined to their respective congressional districts by doing:

```sql
SELECT a.globaleventid, x.statefp, x.namelsad
FROM public.gdelt_full_113 a
JOIN public."113th_congress_shp" x
ON ST_Within(ST_SetSRID(a.action_coord , 4269)::geometry, geom)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query requires a *scalar* subquery, but your subquery results in more than one row.
You need *some kind* of JOIN to relate the two tables,for example:

---

```
SELECT a.statefp, a.cd113fp, a.geoid, a.namelsad
FROM public."113th_congress_shp" a
WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM public.gdelt_full_geo x
        WHERE ST_Within(
                ST_SetSRID(x.action_coord , 4269)::geometry
                , a.geom)
        )
        ;
```

Comment: This seems to only select the first instance of a point being within a particular polygon, then no longer checks for more points in that polygon. In this case I get 428 points, about as many points as there are polygons even though I have nearly 1 million geo location points. Even if I do SELECT * it still only select 428, is there a way to select all of the points?

Comment: It appears that if I do "SELECT a.globaleventid
FROM public.gdelt_full_113 a
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM public."113th_congress_shp" x
        WHERE ST_Within((
                ST_SetSRID(a.action_coord , 4269))::geometry
                , x.geom)
        ) 
        ;" I get all the points that fall into any of the polygons, but I don't know how to get the columns from the 113th_congress_shp table. I think there must be some join, but there aren't similar IDs.

Comment: I was able to get what I wanted with the following: "SELECT a.globaleventid, x.statefp, x.namelsad
FROM public.gdelt_full_113 a
JOIN public."113th_congress_shp" x
ON ST_Within((ST_SetSRID(a.action_coord , 4269))::geometry, geom)" This site was helpful https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/joins.html. Thank you for leading me in the right direction!